# Script to add a tag at the end of files in a folder in case that tag is missing

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I'm struggling with a shell script. I have a bunch of xml files, more than 500, and some of them has no end tag `</deliveries>` I created a shell script that works but only if I write the filename in it (I guess I need to use a loop) can someone help me to see If I have to use foreach or any other loop?. What I want is to run the script that reads and correct all the files in the folder

this is what I get:

```
<variable name="_" scope="session">some_Stuff","cause":"object type not supported"}</variable>
<variable name="out" scope="session">null</variable>
</delivery>
```

This is what I want:

```
  <variable name="_" scope="session">some_Stuff","cause":"object type not supported"}</variable>
    <variable name="out" scope="session">null</variable>
    </delivery>
  </deliveries>
```

This is the script i'm using:

```
#!/bin/bash
key_1=`awk '{line = $0} END {print line}' /home/tornasol/filename.xml` #here i read last line
key_2="</deliveries>"

if [[ "$key_1" != "$key_2" ]] #here I compare the last line and the string
then 
sed -i -e '$a </deliveries>' /home/tornasol/filename.xml #here i add the string in
fi
```

Comment: Do I understand right? Your script does what you want, but only for one file with hardcoded path. You want a solution that checks all files in the directory. Right? If so then the title is very misleading. The title describes what you already have, not what you need help with. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I corrected the title. What you wrote is what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/417938/101265):

```
if ! xmlstarlet sel -Q -t -c "//deliveries" /home/tornasol/filename.xml 2>/dev/null; then
    echo "</deliveries>" >>/home/tornasol/filename.xml
fi
```

This check if `xmlstarlet` return error and if yes add the line to the file.   The disadvantage is **any** error will cause add the tag.

Comment: Hi! thank you for your response, I checked first if more errors are found by xmlstarlet process and sadly yes, there are more errors, so this will add </deliveries> tag even if it is present

Comment: @sr_garde, I am afraid `xmllint` will always return error if you do not provide valid `xml`